# Can't instantiate same class twice in PHP

Tags: php, class

I have the following code and I want to connect to 2 servers by passing $redisdb param.
Unfortunatelly the second instance get first connection.

```
$redis = new RedisHandler();
    $redis2 = new RedisHandler('redis2'); //this one gets first $redis connection
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
class RedisHandler 
{ 
    static $db = null;
    public function __construct($redisdb = 'redis') {
        // opening db connection
        return self::connect($redisdb);
    }
    static public function connect($redisdb)
    {
        global $config;
        if (self::$db === null)
        {
            try {
                $redisClient = new Redis();
                $redisClient -> connect($config[$redisdb]['host'], $config[$redisdb]['port'], $config[$redisdb]['timeout'], null, $config[$redisdb]['reservedInterval'] );
                $redisClient->setOption(Redis::OPT_READ_TIMEOUT, 100);
                if (!$redisClient) { throw new Exception("Can't connect to Redis"); }
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                die('Failed to connect to Redis '.$e->getMessage());
            }
            self::$db = $redisClient;
            return self::$db;
            //return $m;
        }
        else
        {
           // return self::$db;
           return self::$db;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, you're statically storing only one connection, not much different from one global variable…

Answer (score 0):

The **RedisHandler** class is developed on Singleton pattern i.e. if a connection already exists then existing connection is returned, thus you are facing the issue.

You may use and close the first connection and then use the second one for resoling the issue.

Comment: Does self::$db keep the connection globally? How can I not do this?

Comment: Yes, as this is not using the instantiated object i.e. $this. You can complete task for the first connection, close it and then create the second connection.

Answer (score 0):

a static keyword is used whenever your variable or your function member is indifferent from the current instance of your object.

Here your

```
static $db
```

is the same for each instance of **RedisHandler**.

First instanciation **$db is null**, but at the second instanciation, because **$db is static**, the variable won't be **null**, so you can't instanciate another **Redis** because of the condition **if (self::$db === null)**

Answer (score 0):

I use PHP with java to instantiate excel class that generates excel file.

$excel = new Excel (...)

then i wanted to generate second file.
unset and $excel = null didn't work.

It worked with:

$excel = $excel->Excel (...)